# submit an html form created from database using for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make an *online poll*.
Currently what i am trying to do is get input from *a form* on a *different page* and then display all the polls on the next page using for loop. Each polling form can use radio or checkbox depending on the creator. I am facing problem with submitting individual polls. As the form is created using for loop, each form as a submit button with the same name.
Another major problem is that if the creator chooses checkbox for polling (i.e multiple choices allowed), i wish to enter each choice seperately in the database.

Is there a way to solve this using AJAX?

[image: *This is how the database looks*]

`

```
 $pollqry2 = "SELECT * FROM pollq ";

 $PollId= $PTitle= $PDesc= $POption= $POption1= $POption2= $POption3= $POption4= $POption5= $POption6= $POption7= $Target_Aud= $SubGroup= $PollType= $CloseDate= $PNotify= $PComment= $PostAs= array();
 $j=0;
 $i=0;

 $pollres = mysqli_query($con,$pollqry2);

 while($poll = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pollres)){
     $PollId[$i]= $poll['PollId'];
     $PTitle[$i]= $poll['PTitle'];
     $PDesc[$i]= $poll['PDesc'];
     $POption[$i]= $poll['POption'];
     $POption1[$i]= $poll['POption1'];
     $POption2[$i]= $poll['POption2'];
     $POption3[$i]= $poll['POption3'];
     $POption4[$i]= $poll['POption4'];
     $POption5[$i]= $poll['POption5'];
     $POption6[$i]= $poll['POption6'];
     $POption7[$i]= $poll['POption7'];
     $Target_Aud[$i]= $poll['Target_Aud'];
     $SubGroup[$i]= $poll['SubGroup'];
     $PollType[$i]= $poll['PollType'];
     $CloseDate[$i]= date('j F Y',strtotime($poll['CloseDate']));
     $PNotify[$i]= $poll['PNotify'];
     $PComment[$i]= $poll['PComment'];
     $PostAs[$i]= $poll['PostAs'];
     $i++;
 }
 ?> 

    <!-- Main content -->
 <section class="newsfeed">
     <div class="box box-solid box-info">

         <table class="disscussio" width="750">

             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <font size="6"> Polls at [Name of appartment]</font>
                     <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                     <font size="3">
                         <a href="#">Active Polls: <span class="badge"> 5</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                         <a href="#">All Poll</a>
                     </font><br>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <table class="news">

                <?php 
                 function dateDiff($start, $end)
                     {
                         $start_ts = strtotime($start);
                         $end_ts = strtotime($end);
                         $diff = $end_ts - $start_ts;
                         return round($diff / 86400);
                     }

                 for($j=0; $j<$i;$j++){ 
                     $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($CloseDate[$j]));
                     $date2 = date('y-m-d',strtotime("now"));
                     $date3 = dateDiff($date2, $date1);
                     if($date3<0){$date4 = "Closed";}
                     elseif($date3 == 0){$date4 = "Today";}
                     else{$date4 = $CloseDate[$j];}

                 ?>
                 <tr> 
                     <td width="748" class="dispad">

                         <h4><b><?php echo $PTitle[$j]; ?></b></h4>
                         <pre><?php echo $PDesc[$j]; ?></pre>

                            <form method="post">
                                <div class="poll-prog"> 
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "1"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption1[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption1[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "2"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption2[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption2[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>

                                    <?php if(!empty($POption3[$j])){ ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "3"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption3[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption3[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php if(!empty($POption4[$j])){ ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "4"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption1[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption4[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php if(!empty($POption5[$j])){ ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "5"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption5[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption5[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php if(!empty($POption6[$j])){ ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "6"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption6[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-orange progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption6[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <?php if(!empty($POption7[$j])){ ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="pull-left col-md-1">
                                            <input class="minimal" type="<?php echo $POption[$j]; ?>" name="Pop<?php if($POption[$j]=='checkbox') echo "7"; ?>" value="<?php echo $POption7[$j]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-5 progress" style="width:400px;  padding:0;background:rgba(148, 215, 250, 0.37)">
                                            <div class="progress-bar bg-purple progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 30%">
                                                <span>
                                                    <label>
                                                        <?php echo $POption7[$j]; ?>
                                                    </label>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="poll-btn"><center>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" name="PAsubmit<?php echo $j ?>" value="Vote" ></center>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                         <br>
                          By 'sender Name' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
                         <font>Closing Date : <b><?php echo $date4; ?></b></font>

                          <p style="float:right"> 
                              VOTES  <span class="badge">5</span>
                              &nbsp; &nbsp; &#124;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                              COMMENTS <span class="badge">5</span>
                              &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                              <a href="">
                                  <img src="plugins/delete.png" height="15" widht="15" align="right">
                              </a>
                         </p>
                         <br>
                         <font>Open to <?php echo $Target_Aud[$j] ?></font>
                     </td>    
                 </tr>
                 <?php 
                 }
                 ?>

               </table>
       </table>
        </div> 
    </section><!-- /.content -->
  </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I have done -

```
function getVote(clicked_id) {                        
     var val = [];
     var userp=<?php echo $_SESSION['newdata'] ;?>;
     var div_id = 'poll'+clicked_id;
     $('#'+div_id+' input:checked').each(function(i){
         val[i] = $(this).val();
     });
     if(typeof val != "undefined" && val != null && val.length > 0){

          //ajax code to submit form

      }else{
          alert("Please Select Choice First");
          }
  }
```

I used an onClick function on the submit button to get its id using it to get the corresponding div's id. After which I found the number of checked inputs within that div, taking their values in an array and passing it to Php for submission using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one class in all the forms and submit particular form using class.

like this :

```
 $('.classname').click(function(){
   $(this).submit();
 });
```

Use checkbox name as array and after form submit. use foreach or for loop to store that in database.